# Understanding this java class

Tags: java, class, methods

Can someone give me a detailed explanation of this code and tell me why it prints out the output that it prints. This is sample practice question for my test. I am really bad at these methods and classes  part. So assume that i have minimal knowledge on this topic. Please explain line by line and tell me as the value changes. So that if a similar question was to appear on the test, i would be able to do it.
The output is apples, grapes, pears, kiwi,oranges,pears,pears,grapes,oranges, 20

```
public Purchase questionSampleInClass(Purchase p1, int newX) {
    newX=30
    Purchase p2= new Purchase("banana", 5, 4.50, 12);
    Purchase p3= new Purchase("plum", 6, 5.50, 10);
    p1=p2;
    p3=this;
    p3.setName("pears");
    p1.setName("oranges");
    p1 = new Purchase("kiwi", 6, 3.00, 3);
    System.out.println(this.getName());
    System.out.println(p2.getName());
    System.out.println(p3..getName());
    return p2;
}

public class PurhaseDemoClassProblem {
    public static void main(String{} args) {
        Purchase oneSale= new Purchase("apples", 4, 3.50, 6);
        Purchase twoSale= new Purchase("grapes", 8, 1.99, 4);
        Purchase threeSale;
        int x=20;
        System.out.println(oneSale.getName());
        Syste,.out.println(twoSale.getName());
        threeSale= oneSale.questionSampleInClass(twoSale, x);
        System.out.println(oneSale.getName());
        System.out.println(twoSale.getName());
        System.out.println(threeSale.getName());
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll do it if you format your code correctly. You'll want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) Java tutorial explaining object references before anything else.

Comment: ahh first time using this site, is this better?

Comment: *"Please explain line by line and tell me as the value changes."* ... You know who's really good at that? Your debugger.

Comment: @Basco Also, can you fix your typos? I count at least three.

Comment: Use the Debugger. It will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Execution of your program starts in the main() method, so let’s start there.

The first two lines:

```
Purchase oneSale= new Purchase("apples", 4, 3.50, 6);
Purchase twoSale= new Purchase("grapes", 8, 1.99, 4);
```

Create two Purchase objects with some values assigned.  (name=”apples”, "grapes") We don’t have enough detail to know what the other values are.

The third line creates a third Purchase object without any values assigned.

```
Purchase threeSale;
```

`Int x=20`     simply assigns the value of 20 to the integer variable named x.

The next two lines print out the names of the first two Purchase objects to the console. (“apples”, “grapes”)

```
System.out.println(oneSale.getName());
System.out.println(twoSale.getName());
```

The next line 
`threeSale= oneSale.questionSampleInClass(twoSale, x);`
calls the method questionSampleInClass() on the oneSale purchase object.  It passes two parameters in the method call:  twoSale Purchase object, and integer x

In the **questionSampleInClass()** method,
The first command,  `newX=30` changes the value from 20 to 30.  *But this is a trick for your test, that value of 30 only is true for the variable newX inside the questionSampleInClass() method.  The value of the variable x remains unchanged at 20.*

```
Purchase p2= new Purchase("banana", 5, 4.50, 12);
Purchase p3= new Purchase("plum", 6, 5.50, 10);
```

Creates two more purchases with names “banana” and “plum”.

```
p1=p2;
```

Assigns the Purchase object referenced by p2 (“banana”) to p1. It came into the method as the “grape” purchase, but is now assigned to the “banana” Purchase object.

```
p3=this;
```

reassigns the p3 Purchase variable to reference the same object as our oneSale. The p3 variable now references the “apple” purchase object.  The “plum” object is lost.

```
p3.setName("pears");
```

this command changes the name of the “apple” Purchase object to now be “pears”.  Note: The p3 variable is pointing to the same object as the oneSale Purchase object.

```
p1.setName("oranges");
```

Changes the name of the Purchase object referenced by p1, from “banana” to “oranges”.  Note: This is also the same object referenced by variable p2.

```
p1 = new Purchase("kiwi", 6, 3.00, 3);
```

The p1 variable is assigned to a newly created Purchase object with the name “kiwi”

```
System.out.println(this.getName());
```

Prints the name of the current object to the console.  The value is “pears”.
“this” is our oneSale variable because we called this method on the oneSale object. oneSale.questionSampleInClass(twoSale,x);

```
System.out.println(p2.getName());
```

Prints the name of the Purchase object referenced by p2: “oranges”

```
System.out.println(p3.getName());
```

Prints the name of the Purchase object referenced by p3: “pears”

The questionSampleInClass() method then returns to main() and assigns the p2 “pear” object to threeSale.

Back in main()…

```
System.out.println(this.getName());
```

Prints out the name of oneSale. “pears”.  *Remember the value was changed by p3.setName(“pears”) which was assigned to the same object as “this” which was oneSale.*

```
System.out.println(twoSale.getName());
```

Prints out the twoSale name “grapes”.  *The value never changed in the other method, because we changed the parameter p1 to point a different object with the p1=p2; command.*

```
 System.out.println(threeSale.getName());
```

Prints out the name of the threeSale Purchase object: “oranges”.  *It was the p2 object that we assigned in the return p2; statement.*

And finally,

```
System.out.println(x);
```

Prints out the value of x. Which is “20”.  `X was not really changed in the other method because it was passed in as a scalar parameter value.`

Comment: I am kind of confused about the part 
(System.out.println(this.getName());
you said this refers to onesale. Since when did onesale =pears?
        Purchase oneSale= new Purchase("apples", 4, 3.50, 6);
isn't onesale apples?

Comment: and than the next part
System.out.println(p2.getName());
at start p2 is assigned banana, where in the code does it get changed to oranges?

Comment: "this" is a special variable in java. It references the object that is being operated on. The statement oneSale.questionSampleInClass(twoSale, x); transfers control to the questionSampleInClass method. While inside that method, the variable "this" references the same object as the oneSale variable in the main() method.

Comment: p2 is assigned to banana to start. then p1=p2 assigns p1 to point to the same banana object.  So when we do p1.setName("oranges");  the name "banana" gets changed to "oranges".  Both variables are pointing at the same object.

Comment: since oneSale, p3, and this all point to the same object. When we do p3.setName("pears"); it changes the object from "apples" to "pears"

Comment: Ok i now understand why -->    System.out.println(this.getName());
prints out pears.
The line after that System.out.println(p2.getName());
I understand why it prints out oranges.
Line after that     System.out.println(p3..getName());
I understand why it prints pears.
I am confused about the part after that. what does return p2;do?
Anyways line after that 
        System.out.println(oneSale.getName());
OneSale is also p1 and this right?
this was assigned pears so it prints out pears right.

Comment: It's the next line giving me some problems.
        System.out.println(twoSale.getName());

two sale is also p2. when we did     System.out.println(p2.getName());
it prints out oranges meaning that p2=oranges
so         System.out.println(twoSale.getName());
shouldn't this print oranges too?
Same for         System.out.println(threeSale.getName());
Why is it oranges :S

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you get through your test.  Note that I haven't given you the answer you were asking for, but instead pointed out a few key things that may help you on your quest.

```
public class Purchase {

        private String name;

        public Purchase(String name, int something, double price, int somethingElse) {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Purchase questionSampleInClass(Purchase p1, int newX) {
            newX = 30;//set newX passed in parameter to value 30
            Purchase p2 = new Purchase("banana", 5, 4.50, 12);//create new instance of Purchase
            Purchase p3 = new Purchase("plum", 6, 5.50, 10);//create another new instance of Purchase
            p1 = p2;//p1, the passed in parameter will now be assigned equal to p2
            p3 = this;//p3 becomes assigned to the instance which called the method questionSampleInClass
            p3.setName("pears");//p3's name will be changed from plum to pears
            p1.setName("oranges");//p1's name will be changed from banana(remember it was assigned p2) to oranges
            p1 = new Purchase("kiwi", 6, 3.00, 3);//a new instance of Purchase is assigned to p1, wiping out the change made in the previous line
            System.out.println(this.getName());
            System.out.println(p2.getName());
            System.out.println(p3.getName());
            return p2;
        }
    }

public class PurchaseDemoClassProblem {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Purchase oneSale= new Purchase("apples", 4, 3.50, 6);
            Purchase twoSale= new Purchase("grapes", 8, 1.99, 4);
            Purchase threeSale;
            int x=20;
            System.out.println(oneSale.getName());
            System.out.println(twoSale.getName());
            threeSale = oneSale.questionSampleInClass(twoSale, x);
            System.out.println(oneSale.getName());
            System.out.println(twoSale.getName());
            System.out.println(threeSale.getName());
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When i run the program it gives me wrong output than the one our professor provided.